# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage showing multiple back buttons

Tags: xamarin

I have several navigation pages that go several levels deep. Each time the user navigates to another page, an additional Back button is added to the top.

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage()));
```

Do I have to manually turn off the navigation bar prior to Pushing the new page or is there some type of setting for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You are already in a Navigation Page, do not a another one, so `Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingsPage());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Sushi mentioned in the comment, you're already in navigation page, you do not have to push a new `NavigationPage` every time.

Just use:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingsPage());
```

You can read more about navigation in Xamarin.Forms here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/